# Should my database have one table or two?

Tags: sql

I have a table `test_cases` which serves as a join table for `builds` and `tests` and also stores information about the `duration` of the test and the `result`(eg. `'success'`, `'failure'`, `'time_out'`) and the `error_message` in case the test_case failed:

```
test_cases
----------
test_case_id  - integer (primary key)
build_id      - integer (foreign key)
test_id       - integer (foreign key)
duration      - integer
result        - string
error_message - string
```

There are a lot of times where the error_message will be blank (probably 99%+ percent of the time). Is it worth storing information about test_case failures in another table? Maybe something like:

```
test_case_failures
----------
test_case_failure_id  - integer (primary key)
test_case_id          - integer (foreign key)
error_message         - string
```

In production there will be tens of millions of rows in the `test_cases` table, what would the pros and cons to both of these approaches be?

Comment: "will be blank (probably 99%+ percent of the time)" - In this case I would probably create a separate table. But skip the `test_case_failure_id` column and use `test_case_id` as PK and FK.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether you have another table should be based on how you use the data and the size of the data.  Here are some examples.

In general, storing a `NULL` error messages uses little or no additional space (depending on the database).

If the `error_message` is really large, then it might swamp the size of the 99% of the cases.  So, any use of the data at all might take longer.

If the error tests start to have other information -- especially numbers and date/times -- then these would (typically) occupy space even when they are `NULL`.  That would be a strong argument for putting the failures in another table.

If you are doing lots of analysis on the errors and little on the successes, then the success records will throttle the queries.  That is another argument for a second table.

However, because of the foreign key references, I would suggest putting all test cases in the same table.  This leaves you with three options regarding the error-specific information:

- Leave that information in the same table.
- Leave that information in the same table, but put those records into a separate partition.  You will need to learn about partitioning in your database.
- Put the error-only information in another table, perhaps with the primary key of that table being a foreign key reference to `test_cases`.

In addition, Postgres has another alternative, which is to use inheritance.

None of these methods are "better" than the others.  They are all viable methods for representing the data.  Which works best depends on how the data is going to be used and the size of the data.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that it is wise to be assigning so much importance to optimization concerns as for such a question to be bothering you enough to ask a stackoverflow question about it.

Do what is easiest, and if you identify a performance concern under real usage, then refactor things.

The easiest would be to use just a single table, and make the error message column nullable nvarchar.  And guess what, this is unlikely to adversely affect performance, because on most RDBMSes, such a field with a null value will occupy just a single bit in the row.

Comment: I was curious about the differences, I think that's enough of a reason to post a question

Comment: Well, okay, for the sake of encyclopedic knowledge.

Comment: I think you're right about premature refactoring though

Comment: You mean that thing which is the root of all evil? Yes. C-:=